# Can't open or create .NET CORE Web Apps after VS 2K17 Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sdk

I had a previously created web API running under .net core 1.1 and recently I installed .NET Core 2.0. Tired of trying to fix the problem by searching I decided to create a new project running under 2.0 just to realize it does not work either. Had a global.json pointing to 1.0 preview3 two directories upward which I deleted but didn't make a difference. Thanks in advance for any attempt of help provided.

Error presented:

> The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found"

- Running "dotnet --info" on cmd gives me version 2.0.0
- Path variables defined (in this order)
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin
  C:\Users\FILENGA\AppData\Roaming\npm
  %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Previous version of VS 2K17 saved projects in a directory other than the most recent. Just had to move old projets to new folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a

> global.json

file in the root of your repo setting appropriate SDK.

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.4"
  }
}
```

Then run

> dotnet --info

again. If it doesn't say 1.0.4 it isn't correctly taking it.

Make sure you have no other global.json files in the rest of your repo

I had a similar issue and that fixed it. See [here](https://andrewlock.net/the-sdk-microsoft-net-sdk-web-specified-could-not-be-found/)

Comment: thank you! I had tryed this a couple of times before. Check my awnser if you want too!

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue.  I ended up moving c:\program files\dotnot up in my path and it fixed the problem.